# Get Podman container ID from inside itself

Tags: devops, podman

What is the most reliable way to get the **Podman container id from inside itself**?

In **Docker** I solved it like this: `basename $(cat /proc/1/cpuset)`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Podman, as it returns `/`.

I already tried `cat /etc/hostname` in Podman, however this doesn't work if the container is started with `podman run --network host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it by peeking `/proc/self/cgroup`

Comment: And probably `/proc/self/mountinfo` for cgroups v2

Comment: It doesn't look like this method works for non-root containers (at least it doesn't when using the lastest Podman release on Windows 10/WSL2). The approach @Zeth mentions is probably more reliable.